# n-th root and Möbius function

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, mobius-function

Let $q$ be a prime power and $n$ a positive integer s.t. $\gcd(n, q) = 1$.
Let $E(n)$ be the set of the complex $n$-th roots of unity. For every positive integer $d$ such that $d | n$ , let

$$Q_d(x) := \prod_{\alpha \in E(n):\mathrm{ord}(\alpha)=d} (x- \alpha)$$

Why does it hold true that $Q_n(x) = \prod_{d:d|n} (x^d -1 )^{\mu(n/d)} = \prod_{d:d|n}(x^{n/d}-1)^{\mu(d)}$, where

$\mu: \mathbb Z_{>0} \to \{-1, 0, 1\}$ is the Möbius function.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that
$$
\prod_{d\mid n} Q_d(x) = \prod_{\alpha\in E(n)} (x - \alpha) = x^n - 1.
$$
The result is then an application of the Möbius inversion formula written in
[multiplicative form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula#Multiplicative_notation), namely
$$
F(n) = \prod_{d\mid n} f(n) \quad \Rightarrow \quad
f(n) = \prod_{d\mid n} F(n/d)^{\mu(d)},
$$
where we take $f(n) = Q_n(x)$ and $F(n) = x^n - 1$.

Incidentally, $Q_n(x)$ is more commonly written $\Phi_n(x)$ and is called the $n^\text{th}$ [cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial).